# The loop is not iterating on all JSON dataset

Tags: javascript, json

Over here in the JSON dataset, the loop is iterating just on the first pokemon i.e true for Bulbasaur only and the loop is also taking the else statement too at the end which is not required. But if I add a break after the loop before else the code is breaking up. If you type any other pokemon's name it's showing "Not found". If you type in "Ivysaur" or any other pokemon name like "Venusaur" it's not showing. Check out my code below.

```
let findpokemongame = {
  "pokemon": [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.71 m",
    "weight": "6.9 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 25,
    "egg": "2 km",
    "spawn_chance": 0.69,
    "avg_spawns": 69,
    "spawn_time": "20:00",
    "multipliers": [1.58],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }, {
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "num": "002",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "0.99 m",
    "weight": "13.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "candy_count": 100,
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.042,
    "avg_spawns": 4.2,
    "spawn_time": "07:00",
    "multipliers": [
      1.2,
      1.6
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }],
    "next_evolution": [{
      "num": "003",
      "name": "Venusaur"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "num": "003",
    "name": "Venusaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/003.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "height": "2.01 m",
    "weight": "100.0 kg",
    "candy": "Bulbasaur Candy",
    "egg": "Not in Eggs",
    "spawn_chance": 0.017,
    "avg_spawns": 1.7,
    "spawn_time": "11:30",
    "multipliers": null,
    "weaknesses": [
      "Fire",
      "Ice",
      "Flying",
      "Psychic"
    ],
    "prev_evolution": [{
      "num": "001",
      "name": "Bulbasaur"
    }, {
      "num": "002",
      "name": "Ivysaur"
    }]
  }]
};

var findname = window.prompt("Enter Pokemon Name")
let checkname = function(findname, findpokemongame) {
  for (let thispokemon in findpokemongame.pokemon) {
    if (findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon].name == findname) {
      let pokemondetails = findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon];
      console.log(pokemondetails);
      for (info in pokemondetails) {
        if (typeof pokemondetails[info][0] === 'object') {
          pokemondetails[info] = pokemondetails[info].map(o => o.name)
        }

        alert(info + " : " + pokemondetails[info] + "\n")

      }
    }
    else{
      alert('Not found');
      break;
    }
  }
}

checkname(findname, findpokemongame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically how your algorithm work is:

- check first element
- is it the one we searching for?
- If yes - alert 'found'
- If no - alert 'not found' and finish the algorithm (break)
- check second element (if previos condition was 'found' (i.e. we was searching first entry))
- alert 'not found' and finish the algorithm (break)

So you should rewrite the logic a bit, like this

```
let found = false;

for (....) {
  if (element.name === findname) {  
    found = element;
    break;
  }
}

if (found) {
  console.log('found', element)
} else {
  console.log('not found')
}
```

But I'd prefer the `find` way as more clear:

```
const found = array.find(function (element) {
  return element.name === findname
})

if (found) {
  console.log('found', element)
} else {
  console.log('not found')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are iterating over all pokemon, but if the first doesn't match you break the loop.

If instead you change the if/else statement to display "Not found" only when having iterated through all pokemon where none matched.

```
if (findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon].name == findname) {
  ...
  // We found a match, display details
  for (info in pokemondetails) {...}
  break; // Break when all the details have been displayed
}
else if (thispokemon == findpokemongame.pokemon.length - 1) {
  alert('Not found'); // We only reach this when having iterated through all pokemon and none matched
}
```

`thispokemon` is equal to `findpokemongame.pokemon.length - 1` when we are iterating through the last pokemon.